# Intentional Comparison Between Pointer & Integer in C

Tags: pointers, gcc, integer, compare

Will the GCC Compiler correctly handle the following?

```
uint32 fn(uint32 adr, uint8 *ptr) {
    return (ptr==adr);
}
```

In other words will it auto cast ptr to an integer that stores the memory address pointed to?

Comment: How could this nonsensical case be "handled correctly" at all?

Comment: Its not a 'nonsensical case'. I program custom instruments that use PIC32s to manage external RAMs/NVMs as well as data in PIC memory. That means a mix of integer addresses and pointers. It works just fine. I just want to understand whether the compiler will convert pointer to an integer representing the pointed-to address.

Comment: Maybe it will. Or maybe it won't. If you want to be conformant, you do the cast explicitly.

Comment: You need an explicit cast one way or the other.  And then you must understand the result is "system dependent".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GCC will handle it correctly -- by diagnosing the error in your code.

C has no implicit conversions between integer types and pointer types (other than the special case of an integer constant `0` being treated as a null pointer constant), and `==` cannot compare values of integer and pointer type.

To correct the error, add a cast (an explicit conversion) to convert `adr` to type `uint8*`:

```
return ptr == (uint8*)adr;
```

or, even better, make the two parameters of the same type in the first place:

```
uint32 fn(uint8 *adr, uint8 *ptr) {
    return ptr == adr;
}
```

Unless you have some specific reason that `adr` needs to be an integer rather than a pointer, but you haven't told us what that reason might be.

C is more strongly typed that a lot of people assume it is.

Comment: I want it to convert ptr to int32, not adr to uint8*. I'll just cast it.

Comment: @DamienHoreau: Why does it matter which one you convert to the other type? (You mean `uint32`, not `int32`, right?)